# Conditional probability problem and Alias Method

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, simulation

I hopefully someone can help me with this problem of conditional probability:

"A disk server receives requests from many client machines and requires 10 milliseconds to respond to each request. The probability of k additional requests in the 10-millisecond service interval is $e^{-0.9}(0.9)^{k}/k!$ for K= 0,1,2,.... If two new calls arrive while the service interval is only partially complete, what is the probability that a third new call will arrive before the server is ready to respond?"

**One more thing: If it's possible, the problem should be solved using simulate with the "alias method". But I don't know the steps to make this.**

thanks!

Comment: I do not think it is clear, but I would read it as asking for the conditional probability that at least three calls arrive given that at least two calls arrive.

Comment: I thought the "alias method" was for generating random variates.  Do you plan to simulate this? Calculation would be easier and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

What you want the probability of three or more poisson events when given that you have at least 2 poisson events.  To find this, apply the definition of conditional probability, and use the law of complements.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N\ge 3\mid N\ge 2)
 & = \frac{1-\mathsf P(N<3)}{1-\mathsf P(N<2)}
\\ & = \frac{1-(\mathsf P(N=0)+\mathsf P(N=1)+\mathsf P(N=2))}{1-(\mathsf P(N=0)+\mathsf P(N=1))}
\\ & = \frac{1-e^{-0.9}(1+0.9+0.9^2/2)}{1-e^{-0.9}(1+0.9)}
\\[1ex]
 & \approx 0.2{\small 76273\ldots}
\end{align}$$

---

The alias method is computing algorithm used to generate a random result. I'm not sure how this would be applicable to this problem, unless you were writing code for a simulation for ... reasons beyond me.

Comment: Thanks, and yes.. I should write a scilab program to simulate the answer, but I don't know how I should use the alias method. I don't want code, I would like the idea about how I would applicable to this problem. Once again, thanks!